# 2 divs 50% inline block not next to each other

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues with this box model. I was having the issue only with Blackberry 4.6, but it's happening on jsbin/jsfiddle as well.  These 2 divs should be 50% and therefore sit directly next to each other, but the last one is breaking down.

**jsbin:** http://jsbin.com/oyujof/1/edit

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whitespace is significant when it comes to inline and inline-block elements. Remove or comment out the whitespace between the divs.

Clarification: the whitespace is the newline character and spaces between the divs:

```
  </div>\n
  __<div class="nav-button">
```

These will render as a single space when you use inline or inline-block.

Comment: See also:  http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Alex is correct. If I remove the new lines it works. I'd like to avoid float if possible as mobile devices can be fidgety. I didn't know space and newlines were included with `inline-block`. Good to know! Thanks!

Comment: Oddly, Chrome, Mobile safari, and android ignore the spaces. jsbin and blackberry do not...

Comment: Did you get rid of all whitespace? It shouldn't but maybe BB does something bad with comments or leading/trailing whitespace. Unexplored territory for me.

Answer (score 1):

The whitespace has width, so your total layout is 50% + space_width + 50%, > 100% so the second div breaks. Either remove the whitespace, or set the width at 49%.

Answer (score 1):

While `float` can come its own issues, using floats in the case is straightforward and may be your only option in the event cleaning up whitespace and/or 49% is not an option.

```
.nav-button {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

**Updated jsbin:** http://jsbin.com/oyujof/23/

Comment: Yeah I know float is an option, but I want to avoid it. Thanks.

Comment: I understand. As noted, `float` comes with its own issues.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify the rules for `.nav-to` as well as `.nav-button` and also float them left. Here's the CSS that fixes it with the HTML you have given:

```
.nav-to {
        width: 50%;
        float:left;
    .nav-button {
        width: 50%;
        float:left;

        &:last-child {
            text-align: right;
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/oyujof/32/edit

Comment: What's the benefit of `inline-block` vs `block` when you're already using `float`? Seems like more styles to achieve the same thing?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Yes you're right, I overlooked that. With float in place, inline-block is not needed. Edited out the inline-block now.

Comment: Still too many styles. Ultimately we'll have the same answer. :)

Comment: Yes I see the only difference in our answer is that you've added the extra .nav-button in html and removed the css style. Whereas I've kept the html the same and added a style, as stated in my answer.

Comment: I didn't change the html. The snippet I provided is only for `.nav-button`. See the jsbin for more.

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the best answer, but if you set each to 49%, rather than 50%, then it works.