# full-screen fit images in two columns

Tags: html, css, image

I'm a beginner and I tried to make one page by myself, however, the result is not good. I will try to explain what I need: Full-screen page with two images, one image will cover 50% of horizontal space of browser window, and second image will be on right side covering the rest of this page. I need both images to be responsive and to always keep 100% height. When the window is resized, left and right sides of both images will be cropped.
Very similar to this: http://www.gt3themes.com/website-templates/soho/striped_landing.html

Is this difficult to make? I tried to follow some guides on the web, but the result was that my images were stretched and not cropped. Maybe I am completely wrong and I need to create two columns and then put images inside?
I will appreciate any help.

My current code is:

```
.photo{
    size: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.photo img{
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The site you linked more or less did something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/xnLn6s5o/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left" class="halfwidthcontainer">
        <div id="left-image" class="image"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="halfwidthcontainer">
        <div id="right-image" class="image"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body, #container, #left, #right, #left-image, #right-image {
    height:100%;
}

.halfwidthcontainer {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.image {
    background-size: container;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;

}

#left-image {
    background-color: red;
    background-image: url('');
}

#right-image {
    background-color: blue;
    background-image: url('');
}
```

The general idea is that two containers sit side by side, `float`ed (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14268304/3736369) as why to use `float`s to position containers side by side instead of `inline-block`).

The idea thereafter is to explot the CSS `background` property which will allow you to get the overflow/positioning effects you want. You can read more about that [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/).

You're going to want to fill in the `background-image` properties of the `#left-image` and `#right-image` IDs to add the images you want.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot both of you guys!
I just added `background-size: cover; ` and now it is exactly as I wanted it! 
Thanks again